# Derived class doesn't have the base class attribute's value

Tags: ruby

```
module Module1
  class Base1
    class << self
      attr_accessor :attr1, :attr2
      def configure
        yield(self) if block_given?
      end
    end
  end
end 

module Module1
  class Child1 < Base1
     def self.some_method1
       #... some stuff
       "#{attr1}_123"  #for some reason attr1 is nil
     end
  end
end 


  Module1::Base1.configure do |item|
    item.method1 = "43243243"
    item.method2 = "fdsfdsfd"
  end




  data1 = Module1::Child1.some_method1 #it doesn't return what I expect
```

For some reason  `attr1` in `Child1#some_method1`  is `nil` unlike in `Module1::Base1.method1` where it has a value. I wonder why and what should I do to get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I guess there should be `s/method/attr/g` in:

```
Module1::Base1.configure do |item|
  item.method1 = "43243243"
  item.method2 = "fdsfdsfd"
end
```

Secondary, in `some_method1` we’d call eigenclass’ attr:

```
#... some stuff
"#{Base1.attr1}_123"  #for some reason attr1 is nil
```

yielding:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

module Module1
  class Base1
    class << self
      attr_accessor :attr1, :attr2
      def configure
        yield(self) if block_given?
      end
    end
  end
end 

module Module1
  class Child1 < Base1
     def self.some_method1
       #... some stuff
       "#{Base1.attr1}_123"  #for some reason attr1 is nil
     end
  end
end

Module1::Base1.configure do |item|
  item.attr1 = "43243243"
  item.attr2 = "fdsfdsfd"
end

puts Module1::Child1.some_method1 #it does return what I expect
```

Gives:

```
$ /tmp/a.rb
43243243_123
```

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessor` creates instance variables, so your code is creating class instance variables: since classes are objects they can have instance variables too. These variables aren't inherited.

There are also class variables (`@@foo`), which can be surprising  - if you change the value in a derived class it changes it for the entire hierarchy.

Ruby doesn't have a type of variable which is inherited in the same way that method inheritance works. Libraries such as active support add a version of `attr_accessor` (active support calls it `class_attribute`) which sets up the right hooks to create accessors that behave like this - you could have a look at the source for that

Comment: the question is how to avoid that and not why does it happen.

Comment: Well the alternatives are to use @@var or to borrow active support's class_attribute thing

Comment: I don't use neither active support no @@var. @@var is evil.

Comment: @@var is indeed confusing. The active support code should be easy to mimic/copy